# YugabyteDB Postgis does not Installed

Tags: yugabytedb

I tried to install with the following procedure.
But I got an error and *PostGis* is not available.

Follow URL
https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ysql/extensions/

> yugabyte=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;   ERROR:  could not load library
>   "/home/yugabyte/postgres/lib/postgis-2.0.so": libgeos_c.so.1: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

It seems that the shared library is not found from `YugabyteDB`.
PostgreSQL used in `YugabyteDB` does not refer to the shared library on the OS, but it is due to referring to its own shared library.

```
[root@yb-tserver-n1 bin]# pwd  
/home/yugabyte/postgres/bin  
[root@yb-tserver-n1 bin]# ldd postgres  
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe88f7000)  
        libatomic.so.1 => /home/yugabyte/linuxbrew/lib/libatomic.so.1 (0x00007f38ac457000)  
        libm.so.6 => /home/yugabyte/linuxbrew/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f38ac152000)  
        libssl.so.1.0.0 => /home/yugabyte/linuxbrew/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f38abedb000)  
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /home/yugabyte/linuxbrew/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f38aba5d000)   
        librt.so.1 => /home/yugabyte/linuxbrew/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f38ab854000)  
....
```

Please tell me how to resolve.

Comment: YugabyteDB version 2.0.8.0 on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. Just found out that because of some toolchain issues, this is hard to achieve as is today. Could you please open a GitHub issue for this? Would like to get this resolved. Thanks for your interest!